# Binary Tree insertion (in order sorted)

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I've scoured the internet for help on this problem but I need help.  This isn't exactly an ordinary insertion problem for a binary tree, since we don't get to work directly with the tree structure itself.  My prof wrote that himself and has given us functions we can use to write functions pertaining to binary trees.  As such, I can't use nodes and pointers and things. Also this is in C++.

Anyway, so here is the description of the recursive function I have to write ( along with my starting attempt at working with the problem).  Notice it returns a new tree entirely, it does not actually add something to the existing tree.

```
tree_t insert_tree(int elt, tree_t tree)
{
    /* 
    // REQUIRES; tree is a sorted binary tree
    // EFFECTS: returns a new tree with elt inserted at a leaf such that 
    //          the resulting tree is also a sorted binary tree.
    //
    //          for example, inserting 1 into the tree:
    //
    //                           4
    //                         /   \
    //                        /      \
    //                       2        5
    //                      / \      / \
    //                         3 
    //                        / \
    //
    // would yield
    //                           4
    //                         /   \
    //                        /      \
    //                       2        5
    //                      / \      / \
    //                     1   3 
    //                    / \ / \
    // 
    // Hint: an in-order traversal of a sorted binary tree is always a
    //       sorted list, and there is only one unique location for
    //       any element to be inserted.
    */

if (elt < elt(tree_left(tree)){
    return insert_tree(tree_left(left));
} else {
    return insert_tree(tree_right(right));
}
}
```

And here are the functions we can use:

```
extern bool tree_isEmpty(tree_t tree);
    // EFFECTS: returns true if tree is empty, false otherwise

extern tree_t tree_make();
    // EFFECTS: creates an empty tree.

extern tree_t tree_make(int elt, tree_t left, tree_t right);
    // EFFECTS: creates a new tree, with elt as it's element, left as
    //          its left subtree, and right as its right subtree

extern int tree_elt(tree_t tree);
    // REQUIRES: tree is not empty
    // EFFECTS: returns the element at the top of tree.

extern tree_t tree_left(tree_t tree);
    // REQUIRES: tree is not empty
    // EFFECTS: returns the left subtree of tree

extern tree_t tree_right(tree_t tree);
    // REQUIRES: tree is not empty
    // EFFECTS: returns the right subtree of tree

extern void tree_print(tree_t tree);
    // MODIFIES: cout
    // EFFECTS: prints tree to cout.
```

Comment: i wish i knew about stackoverflow in my first year at uni. i actually had to figure this out for myself. is there a specific problem you are having? your start looks like it might not compile as there no left or right variables that you are trying to pass into tree_left and tree_right respectively.

Comment: It's not meant to compile.  That's just where my brain was going.  I'm totally stumped though.  I've been working on this project for days and this is one of the final two functions I need to write so my brain is fried.  I need a push in the right direction.

Comment: That is one of the most disgusting APIs I have ever seen. Your prof claims that to be C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting into a zero-element tree is easy:

```
return tree_make(elt, tree_make(), tree_make());
```

Inserting into a one-element tree is also easy:

```
tree_t new_node = tree_make(elt, tree_make(), tree_make());
if(elt < tree_elt(tree))
    return tree_make(tree_elt(tree), new_node, tree_right(tree));
else
    return tree_make(tree_elt(tree), tree_left(tree), new_node);
```

In general, to insert a new element, you'll need to recreate all of its parents in this manner.

---

**Part 2: Recursion**

We have our base case (a zero-element tree). And we know how to attach a new subtree to the root of our existing tree.

So how to get the new subtree? Well, how about we just insert the element into the current subtree?

The following code will always attach the new element at the far left of the tree, but that should be trivial to correct once you understand it:

```
tree_t tree_insert(int elt, tree_t tree)
{
    if(tree_empty(tree)) //base case
        return tree_make(elt, tree_make(), tree_make());
    else
        return tree_make( // make a new node
            tree_elt(tree) // with the same value as the current one
            tree_insert(elt, tree_left(tree)) //insert into the left subtree
            tree_right(tree) // keep the right subtree the same
            );
}
```

Comment: Hm, where is the recursion supposed to take place to find the appropriate part of the tree to insert the new int? Also, how is the whole tree reconstructed in this way?

Sorry if these are dumb questions, this problem is difficult for me and I'm a n00b.

Comment: @Slims: I've added some more stuff to my answer - does that help?

Comment: Looking through it now.  Using all of my brain power currently, hah, one sec (also thank you).

Comment: Well I understand Part 1.  And I understand why it would insert into the farthest left position everytime.  Do I need an if statement to evaluate how big the elt is?

Comment: @Slims: Yes, you'll need some sort of check to decide whether to insert into the left or right subtree.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, one sec let me test!

Comment: One thing:  tree_elt takes a tree_t as an argument and you put it in as an int.  Do we want the elt that we passed into the function to be here or the elt of the current tree we are passing?  tree_right(elt), I think that sshould be tree_right(tree)

Comment: What I did was after the else I put a conditional that checks if the elt is less than the tree's elt we are inserting into (like your code in part one basically) and put that return statement in both if else, except for the else I changed it to the tree_right and placed it in the 3rd argument slot.  This doesn't seem to quite work.

Comment: @Slims: Yes, you want to be getting the element of the current tree node there. I'll correct that. If it's still not working, could you post the code you're using (chuck it on codepad or something)?

Comment: Sure, sorry.  I'm a noob here, only ever lurked, heh.  Here's the link: http://codepad.org/FTqIUkEv

Comment: @Slims: That looks like it should work ... can you give an example of where it's not working?

Comment: Yeah one minute, I have to figure out a good way to explain since it's hard to do formatting in this little comment box.

Comment: @Slims: Ah right, figured it out. The problem is that you're calling `insert_tree(elt, tree_right(tree))`, even when you're supposed to be inserting into the left subtree.

Comment: Doh, it's always something like that.  Thank you so much.  I wish I could thank people over the internet in some more meaningful way, but you've seriously helped me out a ton and I appreciate it a lot.