# Insertion Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, insertion

Hi I was reading insertion of value in Binary Tree but i am finding difficulty understanding recursive traversal of tree using Java. 
Here is the code:

```
// Java program to insert element in binary tree 
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.Queue; 
public class GFG { 

/* A binary tree node has key, pointer to  
left child and a pointer to right child */
static class Node { 
    int key; 
    Node left, right; 

    // constructor 
    Node(int key){ 
        this.key = key; 
        left = null; 
        right = null; 
    } 
} 
static Node root; 
static Node temp = root; 

/* Inorder traversal of a binary tree*/
static void inorder(Node temp) 
{ 
    if (temp == null) 
        return; 

    inorder(temp.left); 
    System.out.print(temp.key+" "); 
    inorder(temp.right); 
} 

/*function to insert element in binary tree */
static void insert(Node temp, int key) 
{ 
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>(); 
    q.add(temp); 

    // Do level order traversal until we find 
    // an empty place.  
    while (!q.isEmpty()) { 
        temp = q.peek(); 
        q.remove(); 

        if (temp.left == null) { 
            temp.left = new Node(key); 
            break; 
        } else
            q.add(temp.left); 

        if (temp.right == null) { 
            temp.right = new Node(key); 
            break; 
        } else
            q.add(temp.right); 
    } 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    root = new Node(10); 
    root.left = new Node(11); 
    root.left.left = new Node(7); 
    root.right = new Node(9); 
    root.right.left = new Node(15); 
    root.right.right = new Node(8); 

    System.out.print( "Inorder traversal before insertion:"); 
    inorder(root); 

    int key = 12; 
    insert(root, key); 

    System.out.print("\nInorder traversal after insertion:"); 
    inorder(root); 
} 
}
```

Can someone explain how this inorder() method works? Acc to me it should never terminate because it will keep on passing null values again and again and that return statement inside if loop will just loop out of loop and not entire method.

Comment: You apparently don't understand recursion, look it up. The code is pretty clear and it will no longer go down into the tree if the node passed into `inorder` is `null`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917086/binary-tree-insertion-in-order-sorted

Comment: Look for inorder traversal of a tree on youtube or any other platform , you can find some one with explanation in great detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inorder` is being called [recursively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

At any given call of the methods we pass in the tree's left node first, and right node second. These calls would then call the method for the left node, or the right node, however - if the node is null, it returns early. The tree isn't infinite - so at one point a node's left and right node will have to be null, at which point the method returns early and doesn't continue. Hence the recursion is safely broken at some point.

Also `if` isn't a loop - it's a conditional statement. Calling `return` within an if returns from the entire method and doesn't just go out of the if statement. What you must've confused it with is [break](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_break_statement.htm).

Comment: Thanks i debugged this code but after temp = null and recursion is broken..in the very next statement of print how does temp.key prints value since temp is null?

Comment: I presume because it calls `inorder` for both the left and the right node. So if the left node is null, the parent call still continues it's `inorder` call since the parent wasn't null - hence the `print` is being called, and the method is executed again for the right node.

Comment: Thanks i don't understand this parent call part i guess i will have to look up on some recursion docs first.

Comment: if it terminates after temp = null then why inorder call still continues...is there any reason for this?

Comment: When `inorder` is first called from the root node it checks if the root node is null - which it isn't, so it continues its call. It then proceeds to call `inorder` for the left node, which returns early so nothing happens there - the method is basically a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code))
It then continues to print the key, which does happen since we're still in the root's call of `inorder`.
Afterwards it goes ahead and calls `inorder` for the right node, which might still be a noop but that doesn't matter. The print was called either way. Imagine it a bit like Inception :D

Comment: See what i am understanding is according to this program inside inorder() method....first temp will point to 10 since root is "10" then it will check for null and it is not null so it will again call this method passing left node of temp which is "11" then it will again pass left node of "11" which is "7" but after that it will pass null since there is no left node of "7" so if statement will be executed and method will be terminated so after that how come inorder() method is still executed...it should just go to next line after first inorder() call statement in program

Comment: @SahilShokeen your main problem is that you think about **a** `temp` variable, but there are multiple, every invocation of the method has its own `temp`, they have NOTHING to do with each other, you can have hundreds of `temp` variables all over the place in different stack frames, they do not interact.

Comment: @luk2302 but it is a reference variable so first it will be pointing at root of the tree and after left nodes are complete it will point to NULL so mt point is when is temp is pointing to NULL and if statement is executed and control of program comes out of that inorder method then how does Print statement and right side of nodes are executed

Comment: @SahilShokeen **no**, the *value* is passed by reference, if you modify the thing inside `temp`, it will be modified outside the method as well - but if you modify `temp` itself then it does not affect the caller. You simply do not understand what a parameter really is, the different `temp`s have NOTHING to wo with each other, in fact you NEVER change any `temp` in your code, you just create new `temp`s all the time.

Comment: @luk2303 ohh i got it i was confusing it with same variable so what's happening is after every inorder() method call a new temp variable is created which points to left of what it is currently pointing to and after if statement execution of that temp variable method is terminated for that temp variable only but there is previous stack of temp variables whose method execution is still paused which are continued and hence traversal is done....am i right now?

Comment: @SahilShokeen that sounds like you got it, yeah. The phrasing is still a bit off, but I myself am not 100% sure what the right terms in this context are.